# Proof of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=2\lambda h_{ij}$ of geometric flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $F:M\times[0,T)\to(N,\bar{g})$ be a one-parameter family of embedded hypersurfaces that solves a geometric flow
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F=\lambda n,$$
where $\lambda$ is a function to be designated as the speed of the flow and $n$ is the unit normal vector. Now I would like to prove the evolution of the induced metric:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=2\lambda h_{ij}$$
Here is an excerpt from a proof by Huisken and Polden:

> [image]

I was wondering how the second displayed equation comes and how it leads to the third displayed equation.

I suppose what the authors do is simply differentiate $g_{ij}$ w.r.t. $t$, so I get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)+\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right).\tag{1}$$
But how do I combine these two terms to find
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=2\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)?$$
$\bar{g}$ is a symmetric $2$-tensor field, so I do have $\bar{g}(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\bar{g}(\partial_j,\partial_i)$, but does this principle apply equally well to the RHS of (1)?

The next question is how I can manage to expand the product derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(\lambda n)$. Honestly, I do not know what this derivative is supposed to mean.

Could someone please provide me with some details? Thank you.

**Edit.** Why can we switch the roles of $i$ and $j$:
$$\begin{align}
\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)+\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)&=\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)+\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\color{red}j}},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\color{red}i}}\right)\\
&=\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)+\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\color{red}i}},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\color{red}j}}\right)?
\end{align}$$

Comment: Indeed, there appear to be errors here. Have you tried to fix them and see what you get?

Comment: I do not follow you here. $\bar g(U,V) = \bar g(V,U)$ for any tangent vectors $U,V$. It has nothing to do with coordinate vector fields.

Comment: You are right. There is no immediate justification for that last switch. I thought I could play with the symmetry of $g_{ij}$, but it leads nowhere.

Comment: @TedShifrin No problem. Thank you for your attention and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\gb{\bar{g}}$\begin{align*}
\partial_tg_{ij} &= \partial_t(\gb(\partial_iF,\partial_jF))\\
&= \gb(\partial_t(\partial_iF),\partial_jF)+ \gb(\partial_iF,\partial_t\partial_jF)\\
&= \gb(\nabla_i(\partial_tF),\partial_jF)+ \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_j(\partial_tF))\\
&= \gb(\nabla_i(\lambda n),\partial_jF)
+ \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_j(\lambda n))\\
&=\gb(\partial_i\lambda n + \lambda\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
+ \gb(\partial_iF,\partial_j\lambda n + \lambda \nabla_jn)\\
&= \lambda(\gb(\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
+ \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_jn)).
\end{align*}
So set
$$ 2\lambda h_{ij} = \lambda(\gb(\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
+ \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_jn)), $$
i.e.,
$$ h_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(\gb(\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
+ \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_jn)), $$

Finally,recall that $\nabla n$ is the Weingarten map
$$\gb(\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
= \gb(\partial_iF,\nabla_jn) $$
is the second fundamental form. Therefore, the last equation in the excerpt holds.

Comment: Sir, I remember asking you a similar question a couple of months ago. With your help and Polden's explanation, I can now make out at least the derivation. Having taken the normal coordinates, we can refer to the reduced Weingarten equations $$\partial_i n=h_i^k\partial_k F,$$ which should give us  $$\lambda(h_i^k\bar{g}_{kj}+h_j^k\bar{g}_{ik}).$$ Now, the second fundamental form $h_{ij}$ is, of course, symmetric, so we can arrive at the desired equation. BTW, I suppose you meant to write $$2\lambda h_{ij} = \lambda\left(\bar{g}(\nabla_in,\partial_jF)
+ \bar{g}(\partial_iF,\nabla_jn)\right).$$

Comment: To my question: that ***magic*** formula $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=2\bar{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^j}\right)$ is irrelevant to the derivation.

Comment: Oops. I forgot about the earlier discussion. Actually, that equation is correct.